# CSS Simple Gantt Chart (Compact)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to generate a simple gantt chart with html and css and I'm need to figure out how to make it compact, meaning if there is whitespace available the bar should try to fit in a previous row while maintaining the same x distance.

**Context:**

- X axis is a timeline in months
- Each item starts and ends at a given month
- Width and margin are being generated via JS for each element

**Current Output:**
[image]

**Desired Output:**
[image]

**Constraints**

- A JS solution is ok but ideally the solution will not require using an overkill existing js library as the code will be run on a browser extension which would expose a lot of compatibility issues.
- The items do not need to be dynamically movable as for the most part this will be similar to a rendered image.
- No more than 30 items will be rendered.

**Current Implementation Snippet:**
[Edit] I've slightly changed the snippet to demonstrate the need for fixed distance from x.

```css
.timeline div {
    height: 10px;
    background: black;
    margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div style="width: 80px; margin-left: 0px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 40px; margin-left: 35px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 45px; margin-left: 40px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px; margin-left: 135px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 160px; margin-left: 270px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 185px; margin-left: 385px;"></div>
</div>
```

**Other solutions I've tried:**

Originally I started by rendering in JS a monthly matrix of squares and appending an element for each matching month and then using some convoluted logic to help the rendering but I realized it kept getting more and more complex so I backtracked to check if I was absolutely sure there was no simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end the ultimate solution was to use css-grid by having a container with the following CSS:

```
.timeline_container {
    display: inline-grid; // all contents of the container will be treated as grid elements
    grid-auto-columns: 40px; // defines the default width of each column
    grid-auto-rows: 40px; // defines the height of each row

    /* the line below is the key part to making it compact/dense */
    grid-auto-flow: row dense; // keeps rows compact by filling available row whitespace
}
```

And each child element with the following CSS:

```
.timeline_item {
    grid-column: 3 / 5; // defines start and end column where the item
}
```

So the following HTML would render exactly the way I needed it to:

```
<div class='timeline_container'>
    <div class='timeline_item'></div>
    <div class='timeline_item'></div>
    <div class='timeline_item'></div>
</div>
```

I've written a more detailed article about the solution: https://www.cvtimeline.com/creating-a-gantt-timeline-with-css-grid/

css-grid rocks!!!

Answer (score 1):

steps

- set timeline to `inline-flex`
- using double height allows the sub-elements to be arranged up and down

  - *height: 20px;*
- even sub-elements align to the bottom

  - *align-self: flex-end;*
- using **absolute** to position to achieve a dynamic starting position with **margin-left**

```css
.timeline {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 20px;
  position : relative;
}

.timeline div {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  position : absolute;
}

.timeline div:nth-child(even) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
 <div style="width: 80px; margin-left: 0px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 20px; margin-left: 75px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 45px; margin-left: 90px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 100px; margin-left: 135px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 160px; margin-left: 270px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 185px; margin-left: 385px;"></div>
</div>
```

---

**Three elements are overlapping parallel**

you can set align-items to `flex-start` and change the `margin-top` to offset position from above

steps

- one element height * elements count

  - height : 30px ( 10 * 3)
- use default align-items : `flex-start` to reset offset position
- change the `margin-top` to offset position from above

  - **one element hight * level**
  - second : 10 * 2
  - third : 10 * 3

```css
.timeline {
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 30px;
  position : relative;
}

.timeline div {
  height: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  position : absolute;
}

.second{
  margin-top : 10px;
}

.third {
  margin-top : 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
 <div style="width: 80px; margin-left: 0px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 20px; margin-left: 75px;" class="second"></div>
  <div style="width: 45px; margin-left: 90px;" class="third" ></div>
  <div style="width: 100px; margin-left: 135px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 160px; margin-left: 270px;"></div>
  <div style="width: 185px; margin-left: 385px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow. This is definitely a great start. However the issue here is that each item does not necessarily start right after the previous but has a fixed starting position. meaning there could be a blank. This is why in the snippet I have posted I need to use some sort of margin-left. In my case the unit of measure of 1 month is 5px so an item 20px wide is an item that lasted 4 months. Margin-left 90px means the item ended 18 months ago (18 * 5).

Comment: I restore to prev version that has margin-left, is that what you mean?

Comment: I edited the original snippet to give you an idea of what I mean with fixed x distance.

Comment: try this, I using absolute to position

Comment: Wow! You sir are a god! Once again the proof that "If it's getting too complex then you are missing a simpler solution! Tacos to you sir!

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that it only works when 2 elements are overlapping parallel. If there are 3 then it will bet a lil messed up.

Comment: any chance you can help figure out how to make it work when we have more than 3 lines? I've updated the spinnet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178717/discussion-between-chunbin-li-and-marco-yammine).